# Is is possible to migrate my question from SU to SO?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, migration

Is it possible to migrate my question manually (without waiting for 5 votes to close) from Superuser to Stackoverflow? I asked the question on SU at first, but now I realize that only Stackoverflow users could help me because my question concerns programming side.

[Link to the question](https://superuser.com/questions/146057/force-gdm-login-screen-to-the-primary-monitor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your question, as currently written, is inappropriate for Stack Overflow, and I've declined to migrate it.  Let's leave it as it is on Super User.

Please post a new question to Stack Overflow instead.  You will want to follow @Gnoupi's suggestions for rewriting so your post won't get closed on Stack Overflow.  Try to be as specific as possible.

Thanks for asking this question, and for flagging your SU question for moderator attention.  This is the right process to go through.  Good luck with your question!

Answer (score 1):

You can flag it for moderator attention and explain why you want it migrated.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this question is good for Super User as it is.

If it gets migrated on Stack Overflow, you should emphasize the fact that you want to modify the sources, more than the initial ask.

You could as well just remove the "I'm ready to modify the sources" part on the SU question, and ask it again, simply, on Stack Overflow, but centered on "how to modify the sources". Maybe in the future someone will come with a solution on SU without modifying the sources. *(Of course I thought about that only after casting my migration vote)*